# SQL multiple Joing Question, cant join 5 tables, problem with max

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions, lateral-join

I got 6 tables:

Albums

```
id_album | title | id_band | year |
```

Bands

```
id_band | name |style | origin
```

composers

```
id_musician | id_song
```

members

```
id_musician | id_band | instrument
```

musicians

```
id_musician | name | birth | death | gender
```

songs

```
id_song | title | duration | id_album
```

I need to write a query where I get the six bands with more members and of those bands, get the longest song duration and it's title.

So far, I can get the biggest bands:

```
SELECT bands.name, COUNT(id_musician) AS numberMusician
FROM bands
INNER JOIN members USING (id_band)
GROUP BY bands.name
ORDER BY numberMusician DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

I can also get the longest songs:

```
SELECT MAX(duration), songs.title, id_album, id_band
FROM SONGs
INNER JOIN albums USING (id_album)
GROUP BY songs.title, id_album, id_band
ORDER BY MAX(duration) DESC
```

The problem occurs when I am trying to write a subquery to get the band with the corresponding song and its duration. Trying to do it with inner joins also gets me undesired results. Could someone help me?

I have tried to put the subquery in the where, but I can't find how to do it due to MAX.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that using lateral joins makre the query easier to write. You already have the `join` logic all right, so we just need to correlate the bands with the musicians the songs.

So:

```
select b.name, m.*, s.*
from bands b
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) as cnt_musicians
    from members m 
    where m.id_band = b.id_band
) m
cross join lateral (
    select s.title, s.duration
    from songs s
    inner join albums a using (id_album)
    where a.id_band = b.id_band
    order by s.duration desc limit 1
) s
order by m.cnt_musicians desc
limit 6
```

For each band, subquery `m` counts the number of musicians per group (its `where` clause *correlates* to the outer query), while `s` retrieves the longest song, using correlation, `order by` and `limit`. The outer query just combines the information, and then orders selects the top 6 bands.